# How to create an Apache site for domainless requests?

Tags: apache2

How do you configure an Apache site to specifically be used for requests that contain no domain name (i.e. they're coming straight from the IP, http://123.45.67.89/)?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19026877/247542) suggests creating a virtualhost like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /www/default
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

but this doesn't work for me on Apache 2.4.18.

I also tried specifying a `default.conf` site with no ServerName defined, like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /log/ "/var/log/"
    <Directory "/var/log/">
           Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
           Order deny,allow
           Deny from all
           Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but that also doesn't work. All requests to my server's IP timeout while requests to domain names hosts by the server respond instantly.

Looking in my apache error.log, I'm seeing a ton of lines like:

```
[Sun Oct 29 21:13:13.843598 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5650:tid 139875504514944] AH00051: child pid 23179 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Oct 29 21:13:13.843609 2017] [core:error] [pid 5650:tid 139875504514944] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 23179
[Sun Oct 29 21:13:14.845641 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5650:tid 139875504514944] AH00051: child pid 23183 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Oct 29 21:13:14.845704 2017] [core:error] [pid 5650:tid 139875504514944] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 23183
[Sun Oct 29 21:13:14.845733 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5650:tid 139875504514944] AH00051: child pid 23184 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Oct 29 21:13:14.845746 2017] [core:error] [pid 5650:tid 139875504514944] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 23184
[Sun Oct 29 21:13:14.845770 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5650:tid 139875504514944] AH00051: child pid 23185 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sun Oct 29 21:13:14.845783 2017] [core:error] [pid 5650:tid 139875504514944] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 23185
```

I'm assuming that's not good? What would be causing Apache to segfault?

Comment: Your requests wouldn't time out even if the virtualhost wasn't configured properly. Apache is listening on port 80 regardless of which website is being requested. You're not connecting to Apache. Silly question, but are you sure this IP is valid?

Comment: @Appleoddity, It does indeed seem like Apache is crashing for some reason. I've updated my post.

Comment: Your Apache or some component of the OS is broken. You need to fix it, try re-installing or updating.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a bug/limitation in the number of ModWSGI sites that Apache can run simultaneously. I had about 20 WSGI sites running a Django application, and apparently this was causing Apache to crash and take down the "simple" site I was trying to test.

So my above examples actually both work, but I had to first remove several WSGI sites to stop Apache from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Apache uses the alphabetic order of the *.conf files in the `sites-enabled` directory.  So if I had some sites on a server:

```
example.org.conf
example.org-ssl.conf
another-domain.conf
another-domain-ssl.conf
```

and I wanted to use example.org as the "default" site, you could create a symlink to the site you wanted, with a name like `000-default.conf` (Debian does this).

`000-default.conf -> example.org.conf`